# I got this when I tried to change the default user to Abstractuser?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
┌──(venv)─(neo㉿neo)-[~/…/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend]
└─$ python3 manage.py migrate       
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blogapp, contenttypes, forumapp, sessions, token_blacklist, useraccount
Running migrations:
  Applying useraccount.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 130, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 96, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 442, in create_model
    sql, params = self.table_sql(model)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 216, in table_sql
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 346, in column_sql
    field_db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1183, in db_parameters
    target_db_parameters = self.target_field.db_parameters(connection)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1060, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 747, in foreign_related_fields
    rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 734, in related_fields
    return self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1103, in resolve_related_fields
    related_fields = super().resolve_related_fields()
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 712, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Related model 'useraccount.user' cannot be resolved
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
┌──(venv)─(neo㉿neo)-[~/…/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend]
└─$
```

I added AUTH_USER_MODEL in setting and my new User has nothing. just a pass

Comment: Please put your user model here. The issue is from that model.

Comment: I don't understand where you are referring to?

Comment: @DatTT means you declared your User models in `useraccount/models.py`. We need the content of this file to be able to help you.

Comment: from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass